# How better is the GTX 750 Ti over Intel HD Graphics 4600

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, processor, video-adapters

Here's my current config

- Intel i5 4440 @ 3.1 GHz (Onboard GPU -  Intel HD Graphics 4600)
- 4GB Ram
- 1TB HD
- 128 GB SSD
- Running Windows 7 Ultimate (64 bit)
- ASUS H81M-CS  Motherboard

I'm a casual gamer and am also looking at doing a bit of android dev. I was thinking of purchasing and adding a dedicated GPU to expand on the number of games I could play and also to accelerate the android emulator's performance while developing.

I am thinking of purchasing a GTX 750 Ti. However the comments on this [amazon page](http://www.amazon.in/ZOTAC-GeForce-Graphics-Black-Orange/dp/B00IFZ547Q) and this [toms hardware thread](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2705075/list-games-play-gtx-750ti-ultra-setting.html) mention that the following games worked well on this card.

- Crysis 3 -  2013
- Arkham Knight -  2015
- Metro 2033 -  2010
- Batman: Arkham City -  2011
- Need for Speed Rivals -  2013
- Battlefield 4 -  2013
- Tital Fall -  2014
- BioShock Infinite -  2013
- Watch Dogs -  2014
- Battlefield: Bad Company 2 -  2010
- Call of Duty: Black Ops II -  2012
- Ryse: Son of Rome : 2013
- Batman Arkham Origins : 2013

I noticed most games were from pre 2013 with a few from 2015. I have been able to play many of them without a dedicated graphics card. Some of the games I've been able to play are Assassin's creed 1, Assassin's creed 2, Batman Arkham Origins, Watch Dogs with ease. All of which were made around the same time as the games on the list above.

I haven't been able to test the rest yet, but it did get me thinking as to how much of a difference would it make to add a GTX 750 Ti. I'm not looking at maxed out settings and FPS, just decent gameplay.

So my question is

1. Given my onboard graphics seems to function fairly well, are there games I absolutely cannot play without the GTX 750 Ti. (for games till 2015 at mid / low settings with decent FPS)
2. How much of a difference would it make with the android emulator performance.
3. Would the power of my onboard graphics go unutilized in this case.

I hope I haven't stuffed too many questions together, thought of clubing them as they are all related to the same problem.

Comment: I see the following reason for this question being on hold " _the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices_ ". I don't see how I'm not asking for pre-purchase hardware recommendation when I said I'm considering the GTX 750 Ti, also I have explained the specific task (Accelerating the android emulator and casual gaming) what am I missing. How else is this off topic